# How to verbally state $f(y\mid x)\;?$

Tags: functions, notation, terminology

How do we verbally state: $\large f(y\mid x)\;?$

I'm familiar with $f(x)$ as "$f$ of $x$" and $f(x,y)$ as "$f$ of $x$ and $y$" (or $f$ of $x, y$), but what does the vertical line mean and how to state this verbally so that a screen reader would read it correctly?

Comment: is this in the context of stats/probability, or more general?

Comment: @πr8 Yes, exactly the former.

Comment: How do *you* say $f(y\vert x)$ in that context (stats/probability)?  Is its use unambiguous? (I.e., are there other contexts where the screen reader might encounter $f(y\vert x)$ for which the context is not stats/probability?

Comment: Inputting only $f(y\vert x)$, WA interprets it as $f(\text{BitOr}[y, x]),$ and then the output is $f(\text{BitOr}[x, y])$

Comment: @Chelonian In this context, usually read the line as "given". Often it's used in a likelihood, e.g. $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)\implies f(x|\mu,\sigma^2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp\left(\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$, where I'd say "$f(x|\mu,\sigma^2)$ is the likelihood of $x$ given the parameters $\mu,\sigma^2$".

Comment: @amWhy if directed at me: i can only remember encountering it in this context, but i'm not certain this is the only meaningful context.

Comment: I suggest that you look into conditional probabilities of discrete distributions to acquire a more intuitive understanding of the concept before you attempt to understand how conditional probabilities of continuous distributions are defined because there are many similarities between probability mass and density functions.

Comment: I just posted my comment above because in one context, it might be read in a different way that how it's read in some other context.

Comment: You might want to look at this question: [Is there a definitive guide to speaking  mathematics?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35496/is-there-a-definitive-guide-to-speaking-mathematics).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We read $f(y \ | \ x)$ as "f of y, given x." This is useful when we talk about conditional probability distributions.

Answer (score 2):

F of y given x? This is what I heard in probability